# how show real time change in database on android from asp.net web api

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I develop web service of android app with asp.net web api
In android we have to program : users and stores
stores should see last user request in their app
for example I am users and I want to buy some things like rice , after I send my request to server it's save in database. after that stores that are near my location should see my request
My problem is how can I check new user request and send them to stores in real time?
should I use signalR? id yes how?
note: I wrote algoritm of get near store and I just have problem in how to send
my example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Device.Location;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using WebService.Models.Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace WebService
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly mydb db = new mydb();

        public void Send(string storeToken)
        {
            try
            {
                if (storeToken != null)
                {
                    ......
                    ......
                    ......

                                if (distanceInMeter < maxStoreDistance)
                                {
                                    var obj = new GetBuy
                                    {
                                        buy = new AllBuy
                                        {
                                            id = newBuyRequest.Id,
                                            longitude = newBuyRequest.longitude ?? 0,
                                            latitude = newBuyRequest.latitude ?? 0,
                                            time = Convert.ToString(newBuyRequest.time, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                            price = newBuyRequest.price ?? 0,
                                            distanceInMeter = distanceInMeter
                                        }
                                    };

                                    resultList.Add(obj.buy);
                                }



                        Clients.All.sendToShop(resultList);
                    }
                }

                Clients.All.sendToShop("error");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Clients.All.sendToShop("error");
            }
        }

        //************************************
        private class GetBuy
        {
            public AllBuy buy;
        }
        private class AllBuy
        {
            public int id;
            public double longitude;
            public double latitude;
            public string time;
            public double price;
            public double distanceInMeter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems right, you want to know how to do the android side?

Comment: is it true? I want to check every new user request in (.....) in code that I wrote them with linq.Is it true way? if I call this method in other method like AddNewBuyRequest is it send data to store/client?